# Some pages ignore token

Tags: tokens, path-aliases

My node alias pattern is *[node:title].html*. Some pages of the site shows a .html extension and some don't.

I don't know what is the best way to fix that (Update the aliases didn't work, and Deleting the existing aliases could make me a great mess because there are more than 20 pages in the site that almost each one of them has a customized alias).

What would you guys suggest?